# Windows debugging symbols

Tags: windows, windbg, symbols

I have a very strange problem. I am using Windows 7 x64 SP1. I have it installed on physical machine, as well as on the virtual machine - VMWare Workstation 9. I have downloaded Windows_Win7SP1.7601.17514.101119-1850.AMD64FRE.Symbols from Microsoft web site and they are working on virtual machine but NOT on physical machine!!! Can someone please advice me what can cause this issue, or how can I diagnose what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to download and install the symbols if you have an internet connection, calling `.symfix;.reload` will fix the symbol server path to point to the internet, it will then download and cache the correct version of the symbols

Comment: The physical machine has probably installed some security updates. Just grab the live online symbols. The web site will figure out which symbols you need.

Comment: I did this. But when I enter command **lm** this is the output `
00000000`74840000 00000000`748d5000   SYSFER   (deferred)
00000000`76a90000 00000000`76b8a000   USER32   (deferred)
00000000`76b90000 00000000`76caf000   kernel32 (deferred)
00000000`76cb0000 00000000`76e59000   ntdll   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\15EB43E23B12409C84E3CC7635BAF5A32\ntdll.pdb
00000000`ffc50000 00000000`ffc85000   notepad    (deferred)             
...          
000007fe`feee0000 000007fe`fefbb000 ADVAPI32 (deferred)`. As you can see only ntdll.pdb was downloaded and not everything else. Any ideas?

Comment: By default, WinDbg performs deferred (or, "lazy") symbol loading. This means that it is not going to load the PDB until you actually try to resolve a symbol in the module. For example, execute, "x user32!*" and then check the loaded module list again.

Comment: @MilošLjumović Please summarize the answer and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @snoone said `WinDbg` was performing lazy symbols downloading dependent on what `*.dll` I was using (debugging). For example when I was listing `x kernel32.dll` it has downloaded `kernel32.pdb` correctly for my system. One more thing: regrading disability to download proper symbols pack - I think @Raymond Chen was correct - it was because of certain `Windows Update - security updates`. Thanks.